# Can raycasting be done on a html element in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

Here is my code which has embedded html page in three.js . I want to click the html page and make a popup. So is there any way i can do that because i think ray casting can only be done to three.js elements and not the html one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ADN CSS3D Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>

<script>
 
  var controls, camera, glScene, cssScene, glRenderer, cssRenderer;
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates WebGL Renderer
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function createGlRenderer() {
    var glRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha:true});
    glRenderer.setClearColor(0xECF8FF);
    glRenderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    glRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    glRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    glRenderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 1;
    glRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
    return glRenderer;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates CSS Renderer
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function createCssRenderer() {
    var cssRenderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    cssRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    cssRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    glRenderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 0;
    cssRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
    return cssRenderer;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates plane mesh
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function createPlane(w, h, position, rotation) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x000000,
      opacity: 0.0,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(w, h);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.x = position.x;
    mesh.position.y = position.y;
    mesh.position.z = position.z;
    mesh.rotation.x = rotation.x;
    mesh.rotation.y = rotation.y;
    mesh.rotation.z = rotation.z;
    return mesh;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates CSS object
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function createCssObject(w, h, position, rotation, url) {
    var html = [
      '<div style="width:' + w + 'px; height:' + h + 'px;">',
      '<iframe src="' + url + '" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '">',
      '</iframe>',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    $(div).html(html);
    var cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject(div);
    cssObject.position.x = position.x;
    cssObject.position.y = position.y;
    cssObject.position.z = position.z;
    cssObject.rotation.x = rotation.x;
    cssObject.rotation.y = rotation.y;
    cssObject.rotation.z = rotation.z;
    return cssObject;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates 3d webpage object
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function create3dPage(w, h, position, rotation, url) {
    var plane = createPlane(
        w, h,
        position,
        rotation);
    glScene.add(plane);
    var cssObject = createCssObject(
        w, h,
        position,
        rotation,
        url);
    cssScene.add(cssObject);
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates material with random color
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function createColoredMaterial() {
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215),
      shading: THREE.FlatShading,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    return material;
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Creates 3D geometry to place in the scene
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function create3dGeometry() {
    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 200, 300, 20, 4),
      createColoredMaterial());
    mesh1.position.x = 0;
    mesh1.position.y = -300;
    mesh1.position.z = 400;
    glScene.add(mesh1);
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200),
      createColoredMaterial());
    mesh2.position.x = -300;
    mesh2.position.y = -300;
    mesh2.position.z = 400;
    glScene.add(mesh2);
    var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 128, 128),
        createColoredMaterial());
    mesh3.position.x = 500;
    mesh3.position.y = -300;
    mesh3.position.z = 400;
    glScene.add(mesh3);
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Initializes scene
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function initialize() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      45,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      1,
      10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 100, 3000);
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
    glRenderer = createGlRenderer();
    cssRenderer = createCssRenderer();
    //document.body.appendChild(glRenderer.domElement);
    document.body.appendChild(cssRenderer.domElement);
    cssRenderer.domElement.appendChild(glRenderer.domElement);
    glScene = new THREE.Scene();
    cssScene = new THREE.Scene();
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
    glScene.add(ambientLight);
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set( -.5, .5, -1.5 ).normalize();
    glScene.add(directionalLight);
    create3dPage(
      1000, 1000,
      new THREE.Vector3(-1050, 0, 400),
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 45 * Math.PI / 180, 0),
      'http://viewer.autodesk.io/node/ng-gallery/#/home');
    create3dPage(
      900, 1000,
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      'http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile');
    create3dPage(
      1000, 1000,
      new THREE.Vector3(1050, 0, 400),
      new THREE.Vector3(0, -45 * Math.PI / 180, 0),
      'http://mongo.autodesk.io');
    create3dGeometry();
    update();
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Updates scene
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function update() {
    controls.update();
    glRenderer.render(glScene, camera);
    cssRenderer.render(cssScene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // On document ready
  //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  $(document ).ready(function() {
    initialize();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried raycasting using the description given on three.js site but the browser is not showing an results. Can somebody help me with my code

Comment: You are correct that it is not possible directly, however you could raycast the plane mesh. Would it be enough or you want to raycast a specific element in the embedded webpage? In that case you could fist compute the intersection point with the plane mesh, then by using the inverse matrix of the css object you could compute the position in 2D coordinates of that webpage and potentially find what element  is at this position. This is roughly what I can think of, the actual implementation might be a bit more tricky...

Comment: No i don't want to click any specific element on webpage. I want to click webpage as a whole and then make a popup out of the three.js scene so that one can dynamically interact with the webpage @PhilippeLeefsma

Comment: this is what i tried but failed                                                                     var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( cssScene.children );

 for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {

  intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );

 }

Comment: What I understand is that you want to click the the three.js scene and if it intersect the embedded cssObject it displays a pop up, for that you probably need to check intersection with the glScene that contains the planes (meshes), the cssObject probably cannot return an intersection point

Comment: Yeah you got it right . i want to intersect the three.js scene and if it intersects cssobject i.e. the webpage then it should give a popup @PhilippeLeefsma

Comment: I though u wanted to go a step further and check if a specific element, for ex a div, is intersected inside that cssObject webpage. My previous suggestion still stand ...

Comment: Can you give a URL reference that would help

Comment: And Why do you need inverse of matrix to compute the position

Comment: @gman  can you help here